# Unit testing C# creating first test

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

Hello I try to add unit test but looks like its harder that I did think :( Is there anyone who can help me and explain how to make one ?

```
public class USerService : IUSerService
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserType { get; set; }

    public List<UserInfo> GetUserU()
    {
        QuizDBEntities contex = new QuizDBEntities();
        var userU = from a in contex.UserInfoes select a;

        return userU.ToList();

    }

}
```

I did create using "create unit test" but here its becomes to hard for me, im lost and its not that easy like on google tutorials.

```
[TestClass()]
    public class USerServiceTest
    {


        private TestContext testContextInstance;

        /// <summary>
        ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
        ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
        ///</summary>
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }

        #region Additional test attributes
        // 
        //You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
        //
        //Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
        //[ClassInitialize()]
        //public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
        //{
        //}
        //
        //Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
        //[ClassCleanup()]
        //public static void MyClassCleanup()
        //{
        //}
        //
        //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
        //[TestInitialize()]
        //public void MyTestInitialize()
        //{
        //}
        //
        //Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
        //[TestCleanup()]
        //public void MyTestCleanup()
        //{
        //}
        //
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        ///A test for USerService Constructor
        ///</summary>
        // TODO: Ensure that the UrlToTest attribute specifies a URL to an ASP.NET page (for example,
        // http://.../Default.aspx). This is necessary for the unit test to be executed on the web server,
        // whether you are testing a page, web service, or a WCF service.
        [TestMethod()]
        [HostType("ASP.NET")]
        [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\Users\\Drage\\Desktop\\lekcja1\\Dunskiseba", "/Dunskiseba")]
        [UrlToTest("http://localhost/Dunskiseba")]
        public void USerServiceConstructorTest()
        {
            USerService_Accessor target = new USerService_Accessor();
            Assert.Inconclusive("TODO: Implement code to verify target");
        }
```

Comment: Be more specific. What isn't working for you. Your `TestMethod`s should show up in the `Text Explorer` view when you have build your `Solution`/`Project`.

Answer (score 1):

Well I"m not really sure where your problem is since you don't give much information, but I can tell that you copied in some auto generated code the most important part is

```
public void USerServiceConstructorTest()
{
    USerService_Accessor target = new USerService_Accessor();
    Assert.Inconclusive("TODO: Implement code to verify target");
}
```

the above method should be used to test your method

```
public List<UserInfo> GetUserU()
{
    QuizDBEntities contex = new QuizDBEntities();
    var userU = from a in contex.UserInfoes select a;

    return userU.ToList();

}
```

your particular method doesn't have much to test and really it should be changed to make it easier to test but that's a different subject.

if you wanted to make sure that GetUserU was returning only one user you could test it like this

```
public void USerServiceConstructorTest()
{
    USerService_Accessor target = new USerService_Accessor();
    List<UserInfo> expected = new List<UserInfo>();

    expected.Add(new UserInfo{ Name = "made up"});

    actual = target.GetUserU();

    Assert.Equals(expected, actual);

}
```

The assert statement is used to specify what your are testing. Although I don't think the above will work as is because I'm asserting equality of two list types. maybe better to do something like this

```
public void USerServiceConstructorTest()
{
    USerService_Accessor target = new USerService_Accessor();
    List<UserInfo> expected = new List<UserInfo>();

    expected.Add(new UserInfo{ Name = "made up"});

    actual = target.GetUserU();

    Assert.Equals(expected.Count(), actual.Count());
    //here I'm going to assume they are sorted
    for(int i = 0; i < expected.Count(); i++)
    {
        Assert.Equals(expected[i], actual[i]);
    }

}
```

in most cases you will create multiple test like the one above for a single method testing different scenarios to make sure that you get back an expected result.